# jQuery UI Tabs: How to Not Load Images Until a Tab is Clicked

Tags: image, jquery-ui, tabs, lazy-loading

I am using jQuery UI tabs. I have 10 tabs, and each tab holds 8 images. Loading these 80 images is making the page load time very long, so I want to wait to load the images in each tab until the user clicks on the tab. I do not want to populate the tabs with ajax calls because I need search engines to index the content in each tab.

Will the [Lazy Load jQuery plugin](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload) work here? It says that it works with tall web pages, but mentions nothing about tabs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately "Lazy Load is currently not usable."

http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload